# advice for creating service or factory (or something else) in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I have a service that accepts four different http requests.
But returns the same data model (different data, but same model structure).
I need to save the results from the service and some specific data, somewhere.
I need a recommendation how to implement this in my javascript angular code.

i implementing this way:
(create a factory that return new instance of class that keeps the results and the specific data).

```
app.factory('myFactory', function () {
    var myDataModel = function (name) {
        var self = this;
        self.name = name;
        self.results = [];
        self.isSearching = false;

        self.get = function (id) {
            self.isSearching = true;

            $http.get('url' + '?name=' + self.name + '&id=' + id)
                .then(function (data) {
                    self.results = data;
                    self.isSearching = false;
                });
        };

        self.display = function () {
            alert('the result of ' + self.id + ' is:' + self.results.join(', '));
        };
    };
    return {
        myDataModel: function () {
            return new myDataModel();
        }
    };
});
```

I don't think that this way is the 'correct' way.
i would like to hear suggestions about how to implement this (maybe a service, maybe directive)?

thanks a lot.

kfir.

Answer (score 0):

I think for the way you are creating the service is more appropiate for Service than for factory, even that will work.

I would write my factory like below without using new:

```
app.factory('myFactory', function () {
var myDataModel = {};

myDataModel.name = name;
myDataModel.results = [];
myDataModel.isSearching = false;

myDataModel.get = function (id) {
myDataModel.isSearching = true;

$http.get('url' + '?name=' + myDataModel.name + '&id=' + id)
    .then(function (data) {
         myDataModel.results = data;
         myDataModel.isSearching = false;
    });
};

myDataModel.display = function () {
    alert('the result of ' + myDataModel.id + ' is:' + myDataModel.results.join(', '));
};
return myDataModel;
});
```

Comment: How the service or the factory fits in here?

Comment: @KfirZuberi just wrapping that code into a factory function, check it now

Comment: ok. but every call to the factory will return the same instance of 'myDataModel'.  i need 2 or three instances of this ''myDataModel.